# defaultProps suppressing incorrect flow error message

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I have a component like this:

```
// @flow
import React from 'react';

type Props = {
  level: number,
  className: string,
  children: any,
  rest: any
};

export const Heading = ({
  level = 1,
  className,
  children,
  ...rest
}: Props): React$Element<any> => {
  const Tag = `h${level}`;

  return (
    <Tag className={className} {...rest}>
      {children}
    </Tag>
  );
};

Heading.displayName = 'Heading';
```

If I pass an invalid type to the level property then there is no error message:

e.g.

```
    <Heading level="3333">Labels</Heading>
```

Running `yarn flow` returns:

> No errors!

But if I remove the default value for value,

```
export const Heading = ({
  level,
```

I get:

17:   const Tag = `h${level}`;

```
^^^^^ undefined. This type cannot be coerced to const Tag =
`h${level}`; ^^^^^^^^^^^ string
```

This is not what I would expect to happen.

Comment: There is something wrong with your markdown markup in that error message. I guess this is a copy&paste mistake?

Comment: have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 0):

In [this discussion](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2549) somebody encountered a similar error when passing a `boolean`to a template string. The answer was the following:

> Flow tries to help catch unintended string-casts, so you'll just need to wrap the bool with `String(true)` here to convey that explicit intent to cast.

Flow shows the same behavior for `null`, `boolean` or `undefined`. If you pass one of these to a template string, it will yell at you.

The suggested solution is to explicitly cast `level` to a string if it was intentionally...

```js
const Tag = `h${String(level)}`;
```

...or (better) to define a default prop which totally makes sense in this context because if flow didn't complain here you would try to render an `<hundefined>`element which is definitely not what you wanted. So it isn't really an incorrect error message.